# Javascript material conditional

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm making a truth table generator in javascript, and I'm trying to see if there's a logical or bitwise operator, such as the and, or, not, or bitwise xor operator, to evaluate if-then statements, like if p then q

It should return something like this

```
p   q   if p then q
T   T   T
T   F   F
F   T   T
F   F   T
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: What is the difference between the last two lines? Shouldn't the third line be `F  T  F`?

Comment: @Isaac no, because if I were to say a statement like: "If you answer this question, you will get reputation from it", and you didn't answer my question, so you didn't get reputation from my question, the promise statement would have come true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one operator that can give that result, but you can use more than one: (!p || q)

```
p  q   !p||q
T  T     T
T  F     F
F  ~     T
```

With `~` i denoted that `q` is not evaluated, so the last clause is true for both truth values of `q`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, each relational operator may be implemented to be its bitwise equivalent:

- whether `p > q`: `p && !q`
- whether `p < q`: `!p && q`
- whether `p >= q`: `p || !q`
- whether `p <= q`: `!p || q`

Additional ones:

- whether `p = q`: `!((!p&&q) || (p&&!q))`
- whether `p != q`: `!!((!p&&q) || (p&&!q))`

As for two above, bitwise xor operator `^` may not work as expected when working with values other than boolean.